# How does browser identify DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

If I have 2 divs on the page:

```
<div/>
<div/>
```

And then I get a reference to the second element:

```
var node = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
```

How does the browser know which node it is? There is no `id` property, just bare nodes. There should be some internal identifier, I guess, but I don't know if it's exposed in the JavaScript API.

UPDATE: Ok, the question seems a bit vague.

What if I have 2 references to these 2 divs: d1 and d2.

How does "d1 === d2" work?

Comparison requires identification. If you have 2 instances of a class, you can tell if they're the same by comparing their identifiers (references). What is the inner identification method the browser uses to compare two DOM nodes?

Comment: This is a good starting point https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div and subpages

Comment: You are grabbing all `<div>`s in order on the page and then selecting the second one via an index... Unsure what you are asking.

Comment: d1 is an object and d2 is an object and you compare objects by the reference, they will never be equal. Again, not clear what you want to be answered

Comment: question is still to vague

Comment: @MisterEpic, if I have 2 nodes, how does browser know which is which?

Comment: @smnbbrv, what is this "reference"?

Comment: @smnbbrv Actually you can compare two dom nodes to each other.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is a pointer, it is just like how browsers know variable a is 10 and variable foo is an array.

Comment: @epascarello definitely, I did not say _you cannot_. They will be compared but the result will be false because the pointers for two divs are different.

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm trying to solve the lack of understanding of how it works problem

Comment: @epascarello where are these pointers? If browser has them, can I have them /use them too?

Comment: What are you trying to solve??? You would need to got into the JavaScript engine and look at their source to see how they keep track of the node reference.

Comment: @epascarello, cmon, I'm just curious, is this a crime?

Comment: How they track it has nothing to do with JavaScript, it has to do with the JavaScript engine that is running in the browser. I am sure that V8, webkit, and edge do it differently under the cover.

Comment: `how it works` is just far too broad a question and someone with 8K rep should already know that. Question should be closed

Comment: charlietfl, no, it's not too broad. @Adam Kewley did a nice job telling that it's a pointer comparison and it's hidden from the JS user. That's what I wanted to know, thanks

Comment: that doesn't mean that the answer should have been given or that the question fits the guidelines of what shouldn't be asked in a question

Comment: I'm a frequent question closer, but I think this one is OK. It's a specific question about programming to which an answer exists (though it may vary from one browser to the next).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser will parse HTML into its own internal data structure. It will have an implementation of `getElementsByTagName` which finds `div`s and returns a collection, which is what you're using. Exactly *how* it internally stores and parses through all the information is--I imagine--browser dependent.

`getElementsByTagName` should, by definition, return an array that follows the sequence of the original HTML text. As part of tokenizing and parsing through the HTML, the browser's internal data structure will record the order in which elements appeared in the HTML to enable your index access `[1]` to work later down the line.

As for references, the browser's javascript implementation will return handles to the `HTMLElements` it constructed during/after (again, this is an implementation detail) parses. Comparing these two handles allows you to make the `d1 === d2` comparisons. In principle, you could implement this behavior yourself by developing a HTML parser in a language, say `C++`, and a javascript interpreter which can interact with your parser's output (for example, a tree structure containing `C++` classes that represent the HTML, again, that's an implementation detail). That'd be quite difficult though so I'd reccomend just trusting that the browser vendors have handled reference logic etc.

### Addenum

Exactly *how* you're able to compare if two DOM nodes are exactly the same is likely, under the hood, very like a pointer comparison. Exactly if it *is* a pointer comparison, again, I imagine is an implementation detail because javascript doesn't intrinsically "have" pointers. The javascript engine itself will, in effect, notice you're comparing two reference (non-value) parameters in a comparison statement (e.g. `===`) and see if both references are poining to the same in-memory construct (again, implementation detail).  So, when you compare `d1 === d2` where both `d1` and `d2` are two reference values you've (for example) pulled from the DOM the underlying javascript engine is: A) noticing they're references, not values (int, char, string) and B) then comparing to see if they're referencing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, but I'm interested in "exactly how" part. I'm familiar about node tree, etc. When I'm giving a JavaScript interpreter the reference, **how** does it identify it to be able to compare it to other DOM nodes during "internal data structure" traversal?

Comment: Tried to explain it in addenum

Comment: Thanks, Adam, it's a good answer. I was hoping for a less opaque JS implementation, but I think it's completely hidden from the JS environment

Comment: Yeah, it's entirely a language detail. You're comparing two "references" to the same item. References are, themselves, an abstract concept used to get around having to work with direct memory pointers and the way in which  a javascript engine has implemented them might be different to how, say, a `C++` compiler implements them. I imagine most js engines will be doing pointer comparisons under the hood though.

Answer (score 0):

Those variables would reference the nodes as exposed by the Document Object Model. If those variable refer to the same node, then they would be equal, otherwise not.

```
<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>
<div class="foobar"></div>

<script>
var div1 = document.querySelector('#foo');
var div2 = document.querySelector('.bar');
var div3 = document.querySelectorAll('.foobar')[0];
var div4 = document.querySelectorAll('.foobar')[1]

console.log(div1 === div2); //true
console.log(div1 === div3); //false
console.log(div3 === div4); //false
<script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zv0vLhuh/

Comment: yes, you're showing that it's possible to identify the nodes and compare them as a result, I'm curious HOW it works

Comment: Equality depends on whether or not two variable are referencing the same node. If you want to know how those references are resolved, that would be specific to the browser implementation.